# What determines /dev entry?

Tags: linux, usb, udev, usb-device

I am trying to use a package called "linux-gpib" to interface with a USB-GPIB adapter. I installed the driver, and didn't get any errors, and plugged in my device.

In Python there is a wrapper for the C API, so I tried the function to open my device, but got error:

```
libgpib: ibBoardOpen failed to open device file /dev/gpib0
```

I checked /dev and sure enough, that device doesn't exist. What DOES exist is a file called "usb_gpib". So it looks like my device is being registered in some way by the system, but it's not creating the right /dev file. I'm not certain, but it's possible that the "usb_gpib" file is what I'm looking for, and was improperly named for some reason. What would determine how a dev file gets named?

---

After some additional searching, I found the /etc/udev/rules.d/ directory.

There is a .rules file here for GPIB, and in it there is the following line:

```
KERNEL=="gpib[0-9]*", ACTION=="add", MODE="660", GROUP=="plugdev"
```

This looks like it is saying that the device created is *supposed* to be gpib0, yet that still is not the case.

---

As requested, this is what "udevadm monitor" printed out when I unplugged and replugged the device twice:

```
monitor will print the received events for:
UDEV - the event which udev sends out after rule processing

UDEV  [32.214427] add      /devices/soc0/amba@0/e0002000.usb/ci_hdrc.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.3 (usb)
ACTION=add
BUSNUM=001
DEVLINKS=/dev/usb_gpib
DEVNAME=/dev/bus/usb/001/004
DEVNUM=004
DEVPATH=/devices/soc0/amba@0/e0002000.usb/ci_hdrc.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.3
DEVTYPE=usb_device
ID_BUS=usb
ID_MODEL=702b
ID_MODEL_ENC=702b
ID_MODEL_FROM_DATABASE=GPIB-USB-B
ID_MODEL_ID=702b
ID_REVISION=0001
ID_SERIAL=3923_702b
ID_USB_INTERFACES=:ffffff:
ID_VENDOR=3923
ID_VENDOR_ENC=3923
ID_VENDOR_FROM_DATABASE=National Instruments Corp.
ID_VENDOR_ID=3923
MAJOR=189
MINOR=3
PRODUCT=3923/702b/1
SEQNUM=1077
SUBSYSTEM=usb
TYPE=255/255/255
USEC_INITIALIZED=941557

UDEV  [32.228951] add      /devices/soc0/amba@0/e0002000.usb/ci_hdrc.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.3/1-1.3:1.0 (usb)
ACTION=add
DEVPATH=/devices/soc0/amba@0/e0002000.usb/ci_hdrc.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.3/1-1.3:1.0
DEVTYPE=usb_interface
ID_MODEL_FROM_DATABASE=GPIB-USB-B
ID_USB_CLASS_FROM_DATABASE=Vendor Specific Class
ID_USB_PROTOCOL_FROM_DATABASE=Vendor Specific Protocol
ID_USB_SUBCLASS_FROM_DATABASE=Vendor Specific Subclass
ID_VENDOR_FROM_DATABASE=National Instruments Corp.
INTERFACE=255/255/255
MODALIAS=usb:v3923p702Bd0001dcFFdscFFdpFFicFFiscFFipFFin00
PRODUCT=3923/702b/1
SEQNUM=1078
SUBSYSTEM=usb
TYPE=255/255/255
USEC_INITIALIZED=2645

UDEV  [32.347470] remove   /devices/soc0/amba@0/e0002000.usb/ci_hdrc.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.3/1-1.3:1.0 (usb)
ACTION=remove
DEVPATH=/devices/soc0/amba@0/e0002000.usb/ci_hdrc.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.3/1-1.3:1.0
DEVTYPE=usb_interface
ID_MODEL_FROM_DATABASE=GPIB-USB-B
ID_USB_CLASS_FROM_DATABASE=Vendor Specific Class
ID_USB_PROTOCOL_FROM_DATABASE=Vendor Specific Protocol
ID_USB_SUBCLASS_FROM_DATABASE=Vendor Specific Subclass
ID_VENDOR_FROM_DATABASE=National Instruments Corp.
INTERFACE=255/255/255
MODALIAS=usb:v3923p702Bd0001dcFFdscFFdpFFicFFiscFFipFFin00
PRODUCT=3923/702b/1
SEQNUM=1079
SUBSYSTEM=usb
TYPE=255/255/255
USEC_INITIALIZED=2645

UDEV  [32.361405] remove   /devices/soc0/amba@0/e0002000.usb/ci_hdrc.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.3 (usb)
ACTION=remove
BUSNUM=001
DEVLINKS=/dev/usb_gpib
DEVNAME=/dev/bus/usb/001/004
DEVNUM=004
DEVPATH=/devices/soc0/amba@0/e0002000.usb/ci_hdrc.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.3
DEVTYPE=usb_device
ID_BUS=usb
ID_MODEL=702b
ID_MODEL_ENC=702b
ID_MODEL_FROM_DATABASE=GPIB-USB-B
ID_MODEL_ID=702b
ID_REVISION=0001
ID_SERIAL=3923_702b
ID_USB_INTERFACES=:ffffff:
ID_VENDOR=3923
ID_VENDOR_ENC=3923
ID_VENDOR_FROM_DATABASE=National Instruments Corp.
ID_VENDOR_ID=3923
MAJOR=189
MINOR=3
PRODUCT=3923/702b/1
SEQNUM=1080
SUBSYSTEM=usb
TYPE=255/255/255
USEC_INITIALIZED=941557

UDEV  [34.314071] add      /devices/soc0/amba@0/e0002000.usb/ci_hdrc.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.3 (usb)
ACTION=add
BUSNUM=001
DEVLINKS=/dev/usb_gpib
DEVNAME=/dev/bus/usb/001/005
DEVNUM=005
DEVPATH=/devices/soc0/amba@0/e0002000.usb/ci_hdrc.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.3
DEVTYPE=usb_device
ID_BUS=usb
ID_MODEL=702a
ID_MODEL_ENC=702a
ID_MODEL_ID=702a
ID_REVISION=0001
ID_SERIAL=3923_702a
ID_USB_INTERFACES=:ff0000:
ID_VENDOR=3923
ID_VENDOR_ENC=3923
ID_VENDOR_FROM_DATABASE=National Instruments Corp.
ID_VENDOR_ID=3923
MAJOR=189
MINOR=4
PRODUCT=3923/702a/1
SEQNUM=1081
SUBSYSTEM=usb
TYPE=0/0/0
USEC_INITIALIZED=1346

UDEV  [34.368446] add      /devices/soc0/amba@0/e0002000.usb/ci_hdrc.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.3/1-1.3:1.0 (usb)
ACTION=add
DEVPATH=/devices/soc0/amba@0/e0002000.usb/ci_hdrc.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.3/1-1.3:1.0
DEVTYPE=usb_interface
ID_VENDOR_FROM_DATABASE=National Instruments Corp.
INTERFACE=255/0/0
MODALIAS=usb:v3923p702Ad0001dc00dsc00dp00icFFisc00ip00in00
PRODUCT=3923/702a/1
SEQNUM=1082
SUBSYSTEM=usb
TYPE=0/0/0
USEC_INITIALIZED=2286

UDEV  [39.006199] remove   /devices/soc0/amba@0/e0002000.usb/ci_hdrc.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.3/1-1.3:1.0 (usb)
ACTION=remove
DEVPATH=/devices/soc0/amba@0/e0002000.usb/ci_hdrc.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.3/1-1.3:1.0
DEVTYPE=usb_interface
ID_VENDOR_FROM_DATABASE=National Instruments Corp.
INTERFACE=255/0/0
MODALIAS=usb:v3923p702Ad0001dc00dsc00dp00icFFisc00ip00in00
PRODUCT=3923/702a/1
SEQNUM=1083
SUBSYSTEM=usb
TYPE=0/0/0
USEC_INITIALIZED=2286

UDEV  [39.013553] remove   /devices/soc0/amba@0/e0002000.usb/ci_hdrc.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.3 (usb)
ACTION=remove
BUSNUM=001
DEVLINKS=/dev/usb_gpib
DEVNAME=/dev/bus/usb/001/005
DEVNUM=005
DEVPATH=/devices/soc0/amba@0/e0002000.usb/ci_hdrc.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.3
DEVTYPE=usb_device
ID_BUS=usb
ID_MODEL=702a
ID_MODEL_ENC=702a
ID_MODEL_ID=702a
ID_REVISION=0001
ID_SERIAL=3923_702a
ID_USB_INTERFACES=:ff0000:
ID_VENDOR=3923
ID_VENDOR_ENC=3923
ID_VENDOR_FROM_DATABASE=National Instruments Corp.
ID_VENDOR_ID=3923
MAJOR=189
MINOR=4
PRODUCT=3923/702a/1
SEQNUM=1084
SUBSYSTEM=usb
TYPE=0/0/0
USEC_INITIALIZED=1346
```

Comment: @MarkPlotnick I ran the command and replugged the device twice. I included it in my original question.

Comment: Sorry, I should've asked for a little more detail. Can you run `sudo udevadm monitor --udev --environment ` while plugging in your device and show what it prints out?

Comment: @MarkPlotnick OK, I have the longer version added now

Comment: I'll look into what created the `/dev/usb_gpib`. What Linux distro are you using and where did the `linux-gpib` package come from?

Comment: Make a Symlink `KERNEL=="gpib[0-9]*", ACTION=="add", SYMLINK+="gpib0%n, MODE="660", GROUP=="plugdev"